# Outlook executable reportedly not found (but it really is there)

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm running Windows 10 Professional and Outlook 2010. When I attempt to launch Outlook, the following error arises

> "Windows cannot find 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\OUTLOOK.EXE'.
>   Make sure you typed the name correctly"

I verified that `outlook.exe` is actually in the correct folder, and when I select the actual executable file in the specified folder, it provides the same error. An attempt to launch using the command line also resulted in the same error.

This started happening today. Restarting the computer proved fruitless and a Windows Defender scan did not identify any threats. The computer is not on a corporate domain.

All of the other Microsoft Office products are working just fine.

Comment: I have lots of ideas, but none of them are related to your post. Assuming your real question is "*How do I resolve this?*", then I have a few of question for you...1) how long has this been happening? 2) have you rebooted the PC to see if that resolves it? 3) have you ran antivirus and anti-malware scans? 4) is this PC on a corporate domain? Please answer these questions by [edit]ing your post.

Comment: You didn't mention if you'd tried the instructions at [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive troubleshooting with Microsoft including uninstalling and reinstalling office multiple times including manually editing the registry as [recomended by microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Uninstall-Office-from-a-PC-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8), and taking it in to a microsoft store to troubleshoot, ultimately I ended up completly reinstalling Windows 10 in order to get outlook running again.

Answer (score 1):

Open Windows Registry Editor (you'll need to be local admin)
Navigate to Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\OUTLOOK.EXE

Ensure BOTH entries as follows are there, if not create the REG_SZ entries or ammend whats there e.g. (Default) may be there but empty.

(Default)
REG_SZ   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE

Path
REG_SZ   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\

Restart machine and try it! Hope this works, Regards Eddie M

(The above assumes you are running Office2016 or above, if not find the relating Reg paths and ammend accordingly.)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but thought I'd add my solution.

Tried office 2010 repair which didn't work

Tried disabling Avast anti virus

In the end I renamed the office14 folder to office14 new and recreated the shortcuts to get it working.  Not ideal but saved me reinstalling windows.

Would of liked to get to the bottom of it but ran out of time.